# Add Effects in the Selection of the Radio Button (Label)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multi-step HTML form.

When the buttons are selected, an automatic transition to the next step with JavaScript is provided.

How can I add an effect when the buttons are selected?

I want the background to be blue and the text to be white when the button is selected. If possible, with JavaScript.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';

  $('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(e) {

    console.log($(this).val());
    $(this).parents('.test-step').next().addClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.test-step').removeClass('active');
  })

  $('.test-step .prev-btn').on('click', function(e) {

    $(this).parents('.test-step').prev().addClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.test-step').removeClass('active');
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="radio" name="calisan-sayisi" value="1 - 2" class="form-control" id="1 - 2">
  <label for="1 - 2">1 - 2</label>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add your css code to question.

Comment: if you have only one box why dont you use checkbox ?

Comment: There are More Than One Radio Button. I Just Added Someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
input:checked + label {background: blue; color: white}
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer browsers, you can set the `accent-color` property of CSS. It's a native implementation of what you are trying to achieve.

```css
input {
  accent-color: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.accent-colored {
  accent-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<!-- Checkbox with auto accent-color. -->
<input type="checkbox" checked />

<!-- Checkbox with specific accent-color. -->
<input type="checkbox" class="accent-colored" checked />
```

To learn more please visit the related [MDN docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color).

It's important to note that as of the time of writing this feature is not supported in all modern browsers. The currently supported browsers are Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. You can always check the [compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color#browser_compatibility) about up to date information,

Comment: There are already much more elaborate answers to the question. Your solution also seems to work only in a handful of browsers. Add some arguments if you think your answer is in some way better than other.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: Edited the answer to provide an example of an answer with inlined details instead of providing a link only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stilish your radio button why don´t use CSS. What is the problem?
https://codepen.io/carlos-turpin-trives/pen/QWgzrwr

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="select" id="option-1" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="select" id="option-2">
      <label for="option-1" class="option option-1">
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <span>Student</span>
      </label>
      <label for="option-2" class="option option-2">
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <span>Teacher</span>
      </label>
    </div>


*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: #0069d9;
}
.wrapper{
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.wrapper .option{
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper .option .dot{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .option .dot::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #0069d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}
#option-1:checked:checked ~ .option-1,
#option-2:checked:checked ~ .option-2{
  border-color: #0069d9;
  background: #0069d9;
}
#option-1:checked:checked ~ .option-1 .dot,
#option-2:checked:checked ~ .option-2 .dot{
  background: #fff;
}
#option-1:checked:checked ~ .option-1 .dot::before,
#option-2:checked:checked ~ .option-2 .dot::before{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.wrapper .option span{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #808080;
}
#option-1:checked:checked ~ .option-1 span,
#option-2:checked:checked ~ .option-2 span{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function (e) {
      console.log($(this).val());
      $('.test-step').addClass('active').change();
      // $(this).parents('.test-step').addClass('active');
      // $(this).parents('.test-step').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.test-step .prev-btn').on('click', function (e) {
      $(this).parents('.test-step').prev().addClass('active');
      $(this).parents('.test-step').removeClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
<style>
  .test-step {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .active {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="test-step">
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="calisan-sayisi"
      value="1 - 2"
      class="form-control"
      id="1 - 2"
    />
    <label for="1 - 2">1 - 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```